# WebForms app using OWIN/MSAL not receiving Authorization Code

Tags: vb.net, webforms, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have been tasked with modifying several WebForms apps by migrating them to MSAL v4. I have downloaded a working MVC C# example ([msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp)) from GitHub and it runs flawlessly. I have managed to emulate the MVC example up to the point of initial token caching.  The OWIN single-tenant sign-in process executes as expected; however, the `Task` assigned to handle notification receipt (`OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync`) is never fired. Consequently, there is no token placed into the Session cache.

The OWIN middleware is instantiated at startup as follows:

```
Public Sub ConfigureAuth(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbLf & "Startup.Auth.vb ConfigureAuth() - STARTED" & vbLf)

    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
        .ClientId = appId,
        .Scope = $"openid email profile offline_access {graphScopes}",
        .Authority = sAuthority,
        .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
        .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters With {
            .ValidateIssuer = False
        },
        .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
            .AuthenticationFailed = AddressOf OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
            .AuthorizationCodeReceived = AddressOf OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
        }
    })
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbLf & "Startup.Auth.vb ConfigureAuth() - COMPLETED" & vbLf)
End Sub
```

Note that a pair of Notifications have been configured by OWIN, one to indicate successful Authorization Code acquisition (`AuthorizationCodeReceived`) and another to indicate authentication failure (`AuthenticationFailed`).  Each is mapped to a corresponding asynchronous Task object.  The Tasks are defined as follows:

```
Private Shared Function OnAuthenticationFailedAsync(ByVal notification As AuthenticationFailedNotification(Of OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions)) As Task
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbLf & "Startup.Auth.vb OnAuthenticationFailedAsync()" & vbLf)

    notification.HandleResponse()
    Dim redirect As String = $"~/Views/ErrorPage?message={notification.Exception.Message}"

    If notification.ProtocolMessage IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription) Then
        redirect += $"&debug={notification.ProtocolMessage.ErrorDescription}"
    End If

    notification.Response.Redirect(redirect)
    Return Task.FromResult(0)
End Function


Private Async Function OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(ByVal notification As AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification) As Task
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbLf & "Startup.Auth.vb OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync()" & vbLf)

    Dim signedInUser = New ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity)
    Dim idClient As IConfidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId).WithRedirectUri(redirectUri).WithClientSecret(appSecret).Build()
    Dim tokenStore As SessionTokenStore = New SessionTokenStore(idClient.UserTokenCache, HttpContext.Current, signedInUser)

    Try
        Dim scopes As String() = graphScopes.Split(" "c)
        Dim authResult = Await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync()
        Dim userDetails = Await Helpers.GraphHelper.GetUserDetailsAsync(authResult.AccessToken)
        Dim cachedUser = New CachedUser() With {
            .DisplayName = userDetails.DisplayName,
            .Email = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(userDetails.Mail), userDetails.UserPrincipalName, userDetails.Mail),
            .Avatar = String.Empty,
            .CompanyName = userDetails.CompanyName
        }
        tokenStore.SaveUserDetails(cachedUser)
    Catch ex As MsalException
        Dim message As String = "AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync threw an exception"
        notification.HandleResponse()
        notification.Response.Redirect($"~/Views/ErrorPage?message={message}&debug={ex.Message}")
    Catch ex As Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
        Dim message As String = "GetUserDetailsAsync threw an exception"
        notification.HandleResponse()
        notification.Response.Redirect($"~/Views/ErrorPage?message={message}&debug={ex.Message}")
    End Try

End Function
```

User sign-in is initiated as follows:

```
Public Shared Sub SignIn()
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AccountController.vb SignIn()")

    If Not HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated Then
        HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(New AuthenticationProperties With {
            .RedirectUri = "/"
        }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not receiving any runtime error messages. There are no build errors or warnings.  The app simply hangs once OWIN has taken care of the login process.

In a nutshell, I am trying to understand why program flow is not being passed from the `GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge()` method to the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync()` Task.  I have verified from the working MVC example this is the expected behavior.

**EDIT:**

After tracing both the MVC/C# and WebForms/VB.NET versions of the app, a side-by-side comparison of the two indicates that the WebForms version of the app hangs at the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication() method.  The associated OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications were expanded to include all six available options.

From MVC/C# Startup.Auth.cs:

```
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
              new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
              {
                  ClientId = appId,
                  Scope = $"openid email profile offline_access {graphScopes}",
                  Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
                  RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                  PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                  TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                  {
                      ValidateIssuer = false
                  },
                  Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                  {
                      AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                      AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync,
                      RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                      {
                          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*** RedirectToIdentityProvider");
                          return Task.FromResult(0);
                      },
                      MessageReceived = (context) =>
                      {
                          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*** MessageReceived");
                          return Task.FromResult(0);
                      },
                      SecurityTokenReceived = (context) =>
                      {
                          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*** SecurityTokenReceived");
                          return Task.FromResult(0);
                      },
                      SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                      {
                          System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*** SecurityTokenValidated");
                          return Task.FromResult(0);
                      }
                  }
              }
            );
```

The following notifications are received:

- RedirectToIdentityProvider
- MessageReceived
- SecurityTokenReceived
- SecurityTokenValidated

-- The OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync() method is fired and an access token is retrieved and cached, as expected.

From WebForms/VB.NET Startup.Auth.vb:

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .ClientId = appId,
            .Scope = $"openid email profile offline_access {graphScopes}",
            .Authority = sAuthority,
            .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters With {
                .ValidateIssuer = False
            },
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
                .AuthenticationFailed = AddressOf OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                .AuthorizationCodeReceived = AddressOf OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync,
                .RedirectToIdentityProvider = Function(context)
                                                  Debug.WriteLine("*** RedirectToIdentityProvider")
                                                  Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                              End Function,
                .MessageReceived = Function(context)
                                       Debug.WriteLine("*** MessageReceived")
                                       Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                   End Function,
                .SecurityTokenReceived = Function(context)
                                             Debug.WriteLine("*** SecurityTokenReceived")
                                             Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                         End Function,
                .SecurityTokenValidated = Function(context)
                                              Debug.WriteLine("*** SecurityTokenValidated")
                                              Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                          End Function
            }
        })
```

The following notification is received:
 - RedirectToIdentityProvider

-- The application hangs while waiting and no other events are fired.

**I am trying to understand why the same OpenID Connect method results in such significantly different behavior between the MVC and WebForms versions of this app.**

Answer (score 0):

You are not [specifying a response type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-the-sign-in-request), so I'm not sure the login is actually working. (Unless MSAL defaults the response_type to id_token, which is possible.)

You should be able to use the [Configuration method from this quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp).

Regardless, OpenIdConnect does not typically use the Authorization Code flow for user login. So, the AuthorizationCodeReceived event would not happen.

Now, if your application wants to access a protected resource (Microsoft Graph, SharePoint, AAD-secured WebAPI) after login, then the AuthCode flow is appropriate. This would be the [Web app that calls web APIs scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly, inserting the response type didn't help. I am confused by "OpenIdConnect does not .... flow for user login." It seems if the AuthCode flow works for login with the MVC example, logically, it should work in the WebForms equivalent. We have repeatedly checked the converted VB code against the C# code and it looks to be fine. The login process also appears to work okay. The Azure AD endpoint responds with the "login.microsoftonline.com/kmsi" URL but that's where we are hanging up. Our client Tasks don't respond. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: Since the authorization code flow is not being used, the event never fires. The code you have in that event belongs in the code-behind of a page that runs after user login. Typically, the redirect uri is an account controller/page. [Look at this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp#add-a-controller-to-handle-sign-in-and-sign-out-requests)

Comment: Paul, I have posted an edit which shows: (a) both the C# and VB.NET versions of the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication method; and (b) the difference in the OpenID Connect notifications being received. To my knowledge the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication method is language agnostic. I don't understand why the two apps would treat them any differently.  Thanks again.